# Removing Highlight from specific word - Java

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea, swing-highlighter

I want to build one sample to remove highlight from words that matches the filter of my app. Therefore I was basing myself on the sample below:

```
    public void removeHighlights(JTextComponent jTextArea) {

        Highlighter hilite = jTextArea.getHighlighter();
        Highlighter.Highlight[] hilites = hilite.getHighlights();

        for (int i = 0; i < hilites.length; i++) {
            if (hilites[i].getPainter() instanceof TextHighLighter) {
                hilite.removeHighlight(hilites[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This sample works to remove all highlights of the Text Area. For example, if I have three selected words and I uncheck the box of one, all of the filters will be removed and I only want to remove the highlight of the unchecked word.. Is there a simple way to check which word matches the filter? or do I need to do it manually? cos until now I found nothing sucessful on my research

Thanks in advance

**FINAL EDIT :**

Logic working for me based on  @camickr answer:

```
public void removeHighlights(JTextComponent jTextArea, String turnLightOff) {


           Highlighter hilite = jTextArea.getHighlighter();

           Highlighter.Highlight[] hilites = hilite.getHighlights();

           for (int i = 0; i < hilites.length; i++) {

              int wordLenght = hilites[i].getEndOffset() - hilites[i].getStartOffset();

              if(wordLenght == turnLightOff.length()){

                  if (hilites[i].getPainter() instanceof TextHighLighter) {

                      hilite.removeHighlight(hilites[i]);
              }

              }
           }                
}
```

Comment: `if I have three selected words and I uncheck the box of one`, please my question whats `and I uncheck the box of one`. , you can to convert view and/or Highlighter to model, to the Document, anyway +1

Comment: how am I suposed to cast this situation? could u guide me more please?

Comment: hmm ... how about keeping your own data structure of the highlighters per word, f.i. a Map<String, List<Highlight>>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to check which word matches the filter?

No.

> or do I need to do it manually?

Yes. Each highlight contains the start/end offset of the highlight. So you use those values to get the text from the Document. If the text matches, then remove the highlight.

Comment: :-) answer could be only `no` and `yes`

Comment: I thought about this logic but I wasnt sure if it should be the write way to be done. Cheers =)

Answer (score 4):

- to see simple example about add/remove Highlighter/instanceof myHighLighter
  [image]

.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.LayeredHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Position;
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class HighlightExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("TextPane.caretForeground", Color.yellow);
        UIManager.put("TextPane.selectionBackground", Color.green);
        UIManager.put("TextPane.selectionForeground", Color.blue);
        /*try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
         } catch (Exception evt) {
         }*/
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Highlight example");
        final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setHighlighter(highlighter);
        textPane.setText("This text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!, "
                + "\nThis text pane contains no html. It supports letter wrapping!");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(new JLabel("Enter word, then press ENTER key: "), "West");
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("wrapping!");
        pane.add(tf, "Center");
        f.add(pane, "South");
        f.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), "Center");
        /*try {
         textPane.read(new FileReader("links1.html"), null);
         } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Failed to load file " + args[0]);
         System.out.println(e);
         }*/
        final WordSearcher searcher = new WordSearcher(textPane);
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                word = tf.getText().trim();
                int offset = searcher.search(word);
                if (offset != -1) {
                    try {
                        textPane.scrollRectToVisible(textPane
                                .modelToView(offset));
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        textPane.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searcher.search(word);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
                searcher.search(word);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) {
            }
        });
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static String word;
    public static Highlighter highlighter = new UnderlineHighlighter(null);
}

// A simple class that searches for a word in
// a document and highlights occurrences of that word
class WordSearcher {

    public WordSearcher(JTextComponent comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
        this.painter = new UnderlineHighlighter.UnderlineHighlightPainter(
                Color.red);
    }

    // Search for a word and return the offset of the
    // first occurrence. Highlights are added for all
    // occurrences found.
    public int search(String word) {
        int firstOffset = -1;
        Highlighter highlighter = comp.getHighlighter();
        // Remove any existing highlights for last word
        Highlighter.Highlight[] highlights = highlighter.getHighlights();
        for (int i = 0; i < highlights.length; i++) {
            Highlighter.Highlight h = highlights[i];
            if (h.getPainter() instanceof UnderlineHighlighter.UnderlineHighlightPainter) {
                highlighter.removeHighlight(h);
            }
        }
        if (word == null || word.equals("")) {
            return -1;
        }
        // Look for the word we are given - insensitive search
        String content = null;
        try {
            Document d = comp.getDocument();
            content = d.getText(0, d.getLength()).toLowerCase();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            // Cannot happen
            return -1;
        }
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int wordSize = word.length();
        while ((lastIndex = content.indexOf(word, lastIndex)) != -1) {
            int endIndex = lastIndex + wordSize;
            try {
                highlighter.addHighlight(lastIndex, endIndex, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                // Nothing to do
            }
            if (firstOffset == -1) {
                firstOffset = lastIndex;
            }
            lastIndex = endIndex;
        }
        return firstOffset;
    }
    protected JTextComponent comp;
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
}

class UnderlineHighlighter extends DefaultHighlighter {

    public UnderlineHighlighter(Color c) {
        painter = (c == null ? sharedPainter : new UnderlineHighlightPainter(c));
    }

    // Convenience method to add a highlight with
    // the default painter.
    public Object addHighlight(int p0, int p1) throws BadLocationException {
        return addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDrawsLayeredHighlights(boolean newValue) {
        // Illegal if false - we only support layered highlights
        if (newValue == false) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "UnderlineHighlighter only draws layered highlights");
        }
        super.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(true);
    }

    // Painter for underlined highlights
    public static class UnderlineHighlightPainter extends LayeredHighlighter.LayerPainter {

        public UnderlineHighlightPainter(Color c) {
            color = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, int offs0, int offs1, Shape bounds,
                JTextComponent c) {
            // Do nothing: this method will never be called
        }

        @Override
        public Shape paintLayer(Graphics g, int offs0, int offs1, Shape bounds,
                JTextComponent c, View view) {
            g.setColor(color == null ? c.getSelectionColor() : color);
            Rectangle alloc = null;
            if (offs0 == view.getStartOffset() && offs1 == view.getEndOffset()) {
                if (bounds instanceof Rectangle) {
                    alloc = (Rectangle) bounds;
                } else {
                    alloc = bounds.getBounds();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Shape shape = view.modelToView(offs0,
                            Position.Bias.Forward, offs1,
                            Position.Bias.Backward, bounds);
                    alloc = (shape instanceof Rectangle) ? (Rectangle) shape
                            : shape.getBounds();
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont());
            int baseline = alloc.y + alloc.height - fm.getDescent() + 1;
            g.drawLine(alloc.x, baseline, alloc.x + alloc.width, baseline);
            g.drawLine(alloc.x, baseline + 1, alloc.x + alloc.width, baseline + 1);
            return alloc;
        }
        protected Color color; // The color for the underline
    }
    // Shared painter used for default highlighting
    protected static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter sharedPainter = new UnderlineHighlightPainter(
            null);
    // Painter used for this highlighter
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
}
```

Comment: =/ this example works with string and for one consecutive string, handle separate string or in my case, to adapt for multiple checkbox is still not fitting...but thanks for the try

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep any highlights you can just remove them all.

```
highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
```