# Remove Hightlight matching String content

Tags: java, string, libraries, highlight, jtextarea

Ok, few days ago I made one post regarding to the remove of Hightlighted text in JTextArea:

[Removing Highlight from specific word - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380350/removing-highlight-from-specific-word-java)

The thing is, that time I made one code to remove Hightlights macthing its size...but now I have a lot of words with the same size in my app and obviously the application isnt running right.

So I ask, Does anyone know a library or a way to do this removal macthing the content of each highlighted string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method to get the text for a given highlighter:

```
private static String highlightedText(Highlight h, Document d) {
    int start = h.getStartIndex();
    int end = h.getEndIndex();
    int length = end - start;
    return d.getText(start, length);
}
```

Then your `removeHighlights` method would look like this:

```
public void removeHighlights(JTextComponent c, String toBlackOut) {
    Highlighter highlighter = c.getHighlighter();
    Highlighter.Highlight[] highlights = h.getHighlights();
    Document d = c.getDocument();
    for (Highlighter.Highlight h : highlights)
        if (highlightedText(h, d).equals(toBlackOut) && h.getPainter() instanceof TextHighLighter)
            highlighter.removeHighlight(h);
}
```